# Which is the best way to convert this array of objects into another?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of objects like this one:

```
[
{prop1: valueA, prop2: valueB, prop3: valueC},
{prop1: valueD, prop2: valueE, prop3: valueF},
...
]
```

I want an array of objects like:

```
[
{x: valueA, y: valueB},
{x: valueD, y: valueE},
...
]
```

I want to create a new array of objects using some properties from the old objects, and I also want to change the names of the properties.
Is the rest operator a good choice to do it? and which one is the best way to use it?
Thanks

Comment: so what is the rules, it is a simple map

Comment: As a lambda function that can be applied to `map`, e.g., `obj => { x : obj.prop1, y : obj.prop2 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `Array.map` will do this, Are you sure noting more?

```js
let results = [
{prop1: 'valueA', prop2: 'valueB', prop3: 'valueC'},
{prop1: 'valueD', prop2: 'valueE', prop3: 'valueF'},
].map(item=>({x:item.prop1, y: item.prop2}));

console.log(results);
```